# How can I see my exception error when deployed on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, exception

I have a save event that is saving fine locally when I run the app from VS.  It gives my successful confirmation.

So I copy my DLL over to the IIS server and place it in the bin folder  and run it, it throws my exception label "Save was NOT successful".

The data in the databases are identical so I'm not sure what is going on if it's the same code same DB and all other save functions work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: what is the exactly exception ? (exception x) -> x.ToString() for read it and saved/show it on page.

Comment: Did you implement logging? Since you see a graceful error message, sounds like you're handling the exception, but you need to log it somewhere.

Comment: @Aristos The exception is just a null reference.  Good idea though I'll try to just display the actual error. Thanks mason

Comment: Ok, show, how can you we help ? we really can not. Locate the real issue, why is null ? for what reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create Custom Error Logger which Logs all the Error in one `.txt` file , and you have to put your all code in `try - catch` block and in `catch { }` block you have to write that error in `.txt` file using `File` Class and you will get that file on root folder(where you hosted you web application) so you can see your all error .

Comment: @Omar- Please click upvote or click 'correct' if above answer is useful.